# Converting unicode characters to the readable format with Emeditor?

Tags: emeditor

I have a huge file with many unicode (C/C++/Java) characters like that :

```
\u00e9
\u00e8
\u00e2
```

Is there a one click way to convert all those characters to the readable format ?

(e.g : `\u00e9` to é)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all text to convert, and then select the **Edit** menu - **Encode/Decode Selection** - **Universal Character Names to Unicode**.